# Confused with script to find ora-2085: incorrect global name

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to create a script that will catch anytime an ora-02085 error is raised and insert into a table so that I see where there are mismatched global_names. Currently my PL/SQL script looks like this:

```
DECLARE
   v1 VARCHAR2(100) := 'MyCheck';
   v2 VARCHAR2(100) := 'Check Global Name';
   vCount NUMBER;
   z VARCHAR2(4000);
   Incorrect_Global_Name EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(Incorrect_Global_Name, -2085);

BEGIN
   SELECT count(*)
   INTO vCount
   FROM dba_tables@(global_name);

EXCEPTION
   WHEN Incorrect_Global_Name THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('please check global_name');
   z := 'Check global name';
 INSERT INTO user.mytable VALUES ('&&2', '&&3', v1, v2, z, SYSDATE);
     COMMIT;
END;
/
```

When running this against a database link with an incorrect global_name, I get this output:

```
ERROR at line 2:

    ORA-04052: error occurred when looking up remote object DBA.DBA_TABLES@(global_name)

    ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1

    ORA-02085: database link (global_name) connects to (old_global_name)
```

But no data is inserted into the table. I tried to also user PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT to raise application errors for the `ora-04052` and `ora-00604` errors, but it still fails to properly insert into the table.

Any ideas/suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Error is probably thrown at parse/compile time, so the exception block does not exist yet. You could test by trying to create a procedure instead of an anonymous block to see if the error happened at create procedure or execute procedure time. (My guess create.)

Answer (score -1):

You may need to do more testing to see what exactly is the cause of the exception. 
**For testing purposes only try**

```
EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
Insert into  logging table(MESSAGE) VALUES  (SQLERRM);
or DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
END;
```

Find out what error is thrown then look to catch it.

Another approach is to get your list of database links and construct a cursor to select from them.  Using pseudo code

```
DECLARE
CURSOR all_links
IS
SELECT 'SELECT 1 from dual@'||d.db_link
FROM dba_db_links d
ORDER BY 1;

BEGIN
--fetch the results of the cursor into a string
--open this string as a new cursor
--have an exception handler within the Cursor scope
EXCEPTION
--catch a problem here and log it

END;
```